# phpmyadmin not installing on freebsd

Tags: freebsd

Hi Im attempting to install phpmyadmin and have become unstuck with the following problem:

```
# cd /usr/ports/databases/phpmyadmin/
# make install
===>  Installing for phpMyAdmin-3.1.1
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/ctype.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/mysql.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/session.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/spl.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/bz2.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/gd.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/openssl.so - found
===>   phpMyAdmin-3.1.1 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/pdf.so - not found
===>    Verifying install for /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/pdf.so in /usr/ports/print/pecl-pdflib
===>   pecl-pdflib-2.1.5 depends on file: /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h - found
===>   pecl-pdflib-2.1.5 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/phpize - found
===>   pecl-pdflib-2.1.5 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20060613/gd.so - found
===>   pecl-pdflib-2.1.5 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/autoconf-2.62 - found
===>   pecl-pdflib-2.1.5 depends on shared library: pdf.8 - not found
===>    Verifying install for pdf.8 in /usr/ports/print/pdflib
===>  Vulnerability check disabled, database not found
=> PDFlib-Lite-7.0.2.tar.gz doesn't seem to exist in /usr/ports/distfiles/.
=> Attempting to fetch from http://www.pdflib.com/binaries/PDFlib/702/.
fetch: http://www.pdflib.com/binaries/PDFlib/702/PDFlib-Lite-7.0.2.tar.gz: Not Found
=> Attempting to fetch from ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/.
fetch: ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/PDFlib-Lite-7.0.2.tar.gz: File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)
=> Couldn't fetch it - please try to retrieve this
=> port manually into /usr/ports/distfiles/ and try again.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/print/pdflib.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/print/pecl-pdflib.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/phpmyadmin.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/phpmyadmin.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend updating your ports tree. See the tutorial here: http://www.unixug.com/content/update-ports-tree-freebsd-62

Comment: Mod parent up.
Sounds like you need to cvsup.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs you just need to copy PDFlib-Lite-7.0.2.tar.gz to /usr/ports/distfiles.

You can get PDFlib-Lite-7.0.2.tar.gz from [here](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/PDFlib-Lite-7.0.2.tar.gz.5478372.0.0.html).